# Scroll contents of GridLayout in ScrollView - Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrollview, kivy, kivy-language

I will say first off I have tried every single example on the web involving kv lang. Not once have I had any success.

The idea is pretty simple: As I swipe up/down/scroll the contents of `GridLayout()` within `ScrollView()` are scrolled up or down. 
The best I have been able to do is have the scroll bar fade into view when running the program. Not able to scroll unfortunately.

```
<Root>
grid_layout: grid_layout
ScreenManager:
...
   Screen:
   ...
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id: grid_layout
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 1
                height: self.minimum_height

                <list of buttons>
```

Binding `minimum_height`in the `__init__` method of the root class (RelativeLayout):

```
grid_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
self.grid_layout.bind(minimum_height=self.grid_layout.setter('height'))
```

I have followed https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.py converting it to kv lang - scroll bar visible, unable to scroll. Also tried every example on Google Groups and here related to using kv lang. Still no scroll :\

Compiling using buildozer and running on Android fails for an unknown reason.

I would appreciate any assistance that can be given.. I am completely clueless at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being unable to scroll was due to a misunderstanding of Kivy's `touch` handlers. Completely unrelated to the code mentioned in my question.

The key is to have `GridLayout` be larger than `ScrollView`, so `GridLayout` can be panned within `ScrollView`.

For those wanting to use `ScrollView` inside `ScreenManager` using kvlang only:

```
ScreenManager:
id: screen_manager

    Screen:
        manager: screen_manager
        id: main_screen
        name: 'main'        

        ScrollView:
            bar_width: 4
            # pos_hint defaults to 1,1 so no need to declare it
            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 1 
                # you do not need to manually bind to setter('height') in
                # python - perfectly possible with kv lang
                # this allows for height to update depending on the
                # collective heights of its child widgets
                height: self.minimum_height
                <----- widgets here ----->
                # for scroll to show/work there must be more widgets 
                # then can fit root.height. If not there is no need 
                # for scrollview :)
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

should be:

```
minimum_height: self.height
```

This is unnecessary:

```
grid_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
self.grid_layout.bind(minimum_height=self.grid_layout.setter('height'))
```

It also won't scroll unless the contents are larger than the scrollview's height:

Full code:

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        # setting the width of the scrollbar to 50pixels
        bar_width: 50
        # setting the color of the active bar using rgba
        bar_color: 5, 10, 15, .8
        # setting the color of the inactive bar using rgba
        bar_inactive_color: 5, 20, 10, .5
        # setting the content only to scroll via bar, not content
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            cols: 1
            minimum_height: self.height
            Button
                text: 'one'
            Button:
                text: 'two'
            Button:
                text: 'three'
            Button:
                text: 'four'
''')

class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass

class DemoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include examples of making sure the scrollbar shows, how you can change the color based on active/inactive and setting the scrolltype (bars vs content).

Comment: The scroll bar is now visible using `.1` as `pos_hint_y`. It briefly flashes as active then fades to inactive. I cannot scroll using `bars` or `content`. Using `pos_hint: 1, .1` designates the scrollview to 1/10th of the screen space, forcing all `GridLayout` content to the bottom of the screen and below. :(

Comment: Could this be related to `ScrollView()` being child of `Screen`? In my case instead of it being direct child to a layout, it is child to a widget aka `Screen` of `ScreenManager()`

Comment: The .1 is just used for an example, adjust accordingly for your own project. Could you show take a picture of what you have, and a picture of what you want to help me get a better understanding.

As for the screen thing, unlikely, you're using that correctly.

Comment: bizarrely, changing the `pos_hint_y` to anything above `.1` removes the scroll bar. The rest of the interface moves up, but the scrollbar disappears..

Comment: The first is using `pos_hint: 1, .1` - the second is how I would like the widgets to be organized, but with the ability to scroll down to view the remaining widgets; the code in my question produces that result https://imgur.com/a/Iksag

Comment: Running your code standalone works. Again the gridlayout takes up only a very small portion of the y axis and increasing `pos_hint_y` causes the scroll bar to disappear and no longer function.

Comment: When the scroll bar disappears, is all of the content of the scroll view visible at once? The scroll bar only appears when you need to scroll.

Comment: With regards to the scroll bar not moving I have it sorted, using you code allowed me to discover my error elsewhere so have an upvote for that. The scroll bar now moves. But is bound to a single button. So if I scroll it only scrolls the first child of gridlayout.. This is confusing as I thought scroll could only take one child, but that child can have as many children as necessary

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have solved the problem - the key is to make `GridLayout` larger than `ScrollView`, so `ScrollView` defaults to `pos_hint: 1,1`. This is done by binding height to self.minimum_height using `height: self.minimum_height'

Comment: you should edit your answer as your current code does not work and might confuse others :)